# Excel formula to calculate sum based on multiple date criteria

Tags: excel, date, sumproduct

I'm looking to accurately show the amount of hours in each phase shown below (Initiation, Planning, Execution, Close). There is a start and end date for each phase - and using the formula below it doesn't factor in dates that are midway through a month.

I have included a column titled 'EXPECTED HRS' which gives the expected results should the formula be working as intended (these were manually calculated).

Really appreciate if someone could assist with this - please let me know if any further information is required.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($I$10:$T$14)*($I$10:$T$14<>"")*(--(DATE(YEAR($L2), MONTH($L2), 1)<=DATE(YEAR($I$8:$T$8), MONTH($I$8:$T$8), 1)))*(--(DATE(YEAR($M2), MONTH($M2), 1)>=DATE(YEAR($I$8:$T$8), MONTH($I$8:$T$8), 1))))
```

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Start date | End Date | **Budget - Hrs** |  | **EXPECTED HRS** |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Initiation | 1/07/2023 | 31/10/2023 | **160.00** |  | **160.00** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Planning | 1/11/2023 | 20/01/2024 | **120.00** |  | **105.81** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Execution | 21/01/2024 | 15/05/2024 | **200.00** |  | **153.55** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Close | 16/05/2024 | 1/08/2023 | **0.00** |  | **60.65** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | **480.00** |  | **480.00** |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Initiation | Initiation | Initiation | Initiation | Planning | Planning | Planning / Execution | Execution | Execution | Execution | Execution / Close | Close |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Jul-23 | Aug-23 | Sep-23 | Oct-23 | Nov-23 | Dec-23 | Jan-24 | Feb-24 | Mar-24 | Apr-24 | May-24 | Jun-24 | Sub-total Hrs |
| Summarised Budget | Treatment OPEX / CAPEX | Budgeted? Yes / No | Budget Ref. | Qty / Rate | Subtotal - Hours | Subtotal - $ | UOM | FY2024 BUDGET - HOURS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Resource 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Hours | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 480 |
| Resource 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Hours |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| Resource 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Hours |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| Resource 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Hours |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| Resource 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Hours |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

I see the appeal of the `SUMPRODUCT` function as a substitute of the `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` functions, but for clarity reasons, I would recomment `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` functions instead, as you can see here:

[image]

The formula, used for this calculation:

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A7,B2:B7,"<>a",B2:B7,"<>b", C2:C7,TODAY())
```

Comment: Hi Dominique - thank you for your reply - unfortunately given I'm using a start and end date for each 'phase' the above formula doesn't work 

Comment: So? Today's date corresponds with the value 45119, so replacing the last criteria part by this is working fine: `C2:C7,"<=45119"`. (I know, now you need to figure out how to work with that datevalue, but it's a step forward.

Comment: @Dominique I think you misunderstood a question. Result is "partial" hours (see "EXPECTED HRS" cells. Say Jan = 40 hours, Feb = 40 hours then date 2023-01-01 - 2023-02-16 should give result 40*31/31 + 40*16/28 = 62.86

Comment: Correct @user11222393 thank you  appreciate you both helping btw

Comment: Can anyone please assist?  This has been driving me crazy 